# How to read SRAM info in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, hardware

Is there any way to read the SRAM info in Linux? I need to read the state of some bytes that are either uninitialized or initialized ?

Thank you !

Comment: you might want to use this http://free-electrons.com/pub/mirror/devmem2.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `mmap()` it if you know your SRAM start address and than access the mmapped memory as usual via pointer arithmetic.

Man: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: and do you know how I can get the starting address ?

Comment: Probably in the data sheets of the hardware you're using.